# Label portions of a dataframe based on boolean value, including previous rows?

Tags: r

For a given dataframe, I'd like to split it based on some boolean value, and then apply a label to that row **and the previous rows up until that point**.

Assuming the following dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = c(F, F, F, T, F, F, T, F, F, F))
```

I'd ultimately like to create a new column that would contain a label for that specific portion of the dataframe.  Ideally, something like the following:

```
x   y   z
1   F   1
2   F   1
3   F   1
4   T   1
5   F   2
6   F   2
7   T   2
8   F   3
9   F   3
10  F   3
```

My current thought is that I need to loop through the dataframe with a function similar to the following (but not exactly):

```
label.portion <- function(test) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
    z <- 1
    if(test$y[i]) { z <- z + 1 }
    return(z)
  }
}
```

What is the best/easiest way of doing this?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `z` column can be built as

```
z <- with(test, sum(y)-rev(cumsum(rev(y)))+1)
```

in order to make every new `z` value start at a `FALSE` `y` after a `TRUE` `y`, as per your example.

Then you can do `cbind(test, z)` to get what you want.

Answer (score 4):

One liner solution  using `transform`

```
transform(test,z= cumsum(c(0,diff(y)) == -1)+1)

    x     y z
1   1 FALSE 1
2   2 FALSE 1
3   3 FALSE 1
4   4  TRUE 1
5   5 FALSE 2
6   6 FALSE 2
7   7  TRUE 2
8   8 FALSE 3
9   9 FALSE 3
10 10 FALSE 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one liner solution which will be slightly faster than other solutions (except `data.table`)

```
test <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = c(F, F, F, T, F, F, T, F, F, F))
test$z <- c(1, head(cumsum(test$y), -1) + 1)
test
##     x     y z
## 1   1 FALSE 1
## 2   2 FALSE 1
## 3   3 FALSE 1
## 4   4  TRUE 1
## 5   5 FALSE 2
## 6   6 FALSE 2
## 7   7  TRUE 2
## 8   8 FALSE 3
## 9   9 FALSE 3
## 10 10 FALSE 3
```

Benchmarks with other solutions provided (excluding data.table)

```
test <- data.frame(x = 1:1e+05, y = sample(c(T, F), size = 1e+05, replace = TRUE))
microbenchmark(c(1, head(cumsum(test$y), -1) + 1), cumsum(c(0, diff(test$y)) == -1) + 1, with(test, sum(y) - rev(cumsum(rev(y))) + 
    1), times = 100)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                          expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
##            c(1, head(cumsum(test$y), -1) + 1) 1.685473 1.758474 1.865409 4.647218  5.091512   100
##          cumsum(c(0, diff(test$y)) == -1) + 1 4.064867 4.379714 6.936561 7.338810  7.657961   100
##  with(test, sum(y) - rev(cumsum(rev(y))) + 1) 2.568766 2.720395 5.396096 5.701176 30.642436   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `na.locf` from `xts` and data.table for coding elegance (and efficiency)

```
library(data.table)
library(xts) # for na.locf
test <- data.table(test)


test[(y), grp := seq_along(y)][, grp := na.locf(grp, fromLast = TRUE)]
test[is.na(grp), grp := max(test[, grp], na.rm =TRUE) + 1L]
```

---

And a far clearer and faster approach

```
test[, grp := {xx <- diff(c(0,.I[y], length(.I))); rep.int(seq_along(xx),xx)}]
```

Note that `diff` uses a for loop implemented in `R`, so an Rcpp sugar implementation) would be faster (I'm sure that a cpp function would blow most of these out of the water)

Comment: I don't think this is working correctly if first value of `y` is `TRUE`

Comment: @geektrader -- great spotting, should be fixed now (a completely different approach)